# A problem with the FLUTTER appeared when I installed it in Windows

Tags: flutter

```
 Flutter (Channel beta, 3.21.0-1.0.pre.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4170], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.21.0-1.0.pre.2 on channel beta at C:\Users\wzalz\flutter_windows_3.19.3-stable\flutter
    ! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to C:\Program Files\Dart\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe, which is not inside your
      current Flutter SDK checkout at C:\Users\wzalz\flutter_windows_3.19.3-stable\flutter. Consider adding
      C:\Users\wzalz\flutter_windows_3.19.3-stable\flutter\bin to the front of your path.
```

What do I do

I tried again and again

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.